# How to selectively populate listbox items using a list?

Tags: infopath

I am new at sharepoint and I am new at infopath too (:
I think the thing I want to do is simple but I can't find the method to handle it.
Here is description :

I have 2 lists. One is the other's parent.

In the Infopath form (to prepare adding form), I want to show selective items from the child list based on value selected in parent list.

First box is listbox, when i choose one item (this listbox lists parent items), the other listbox should list items of this parent item.

Is it possible to do it in infopath?

Answer (score 1):

For such generic question to such huge topic only a generic answer is possible.
AFAIU, it is inquiry for terms for googling.

Infopath Designer 2010 (as well as 2007 and 2003) contains **Master/Detail control** (on ribbon Home for **Infopath Filler Form** or client forms.
It is not available for **Web Browser Form** but internet contains a lot of how-to and step-by-step articles how to do this.

Other keywords:
Child, parent, repeating table

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say 'eliminate' items?

From what I understand, you want to add parent items to one listbox and corresponding child items to the next list box. If that's the case, you can handle this via InfoPath code-behind - using the XSLT.

I might have sample code from my early projects somewhere, will post it here if I find it.

Comment: i mean, when you select an item from list (call it list1) of parents, list items to the next listbox (list2) where list2item.parent = list1.name

Comment: Any way to do it with Infopath rules ?

Comment: I didn't implement using Rules - so I can't vouch for that. 
We had a Categoies (Parent) and Subcategories (Child) lists. Subcategories drop down list was populated based on the Category selected. We implemented this using Formcode. Like I said, I don't have the code with me now. I can maybe find it at home and post it here.

Comment: Just a thought. You might want to change your title from 'eliminate' to 'selectively populate listbox' or something like that to get a better response. 'Eliminate' might throw people!

Comment: Sounds like cascading columns to me

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter to list item here
right click on your listbox -> properties -> than data connection  here you can add filter what you want .