# How to populate multiple-selection listbox according to search results?

Tags: infopath

[How to selectively populate listbox items using a list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39386/how-to-selectively-populate-listbox-items-using-a-list)

i couldnt do what i want with this style. So i decided to change my method.

I want to populate my multiple-selection items, i googled it a lot but i cant get result which is useful for me.

So now, i have a textbox and a button. Textbox is txtSearch, button is btnSearch. When i type something in textbox and press btnSearch, multiple selection listbox should populate, in infopath. 
Maybe we can do this via coding, but in my company i dont have chance to code coz company's pc dont have visual studio :)) and dont let me to install it :)

Comment: You can't install VS, but can you subscribe to [cloudshare](http://cloudshare.com/solutions/developmentandtesting)? And my feeling is that if can't install VS don't use SharePoint. SharePoint is platform, not a standalone product (actually it can be very you will reach limits of the product very quickly). In fact, what is the reason you can't install Visual Studio ? Cost ? Software policy?  Hardware ?

Comment: i'm intern student here, company gave me a pc with intern account :/ And my account isnt administrator at this pc, so i cannot install anything coz admin acc has password and i dont know it.

Comment: i solved the problem. So ready to listen advices.

Comment: if you solved your problem, answer to your question. It may help future people with same issue.

Comment: i mean not to use of features of programmes. Now i can use programmes. By this way for dropdown list i solved problem. I gonna share it here.